# How to automatically update multiple values based on a new value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called 'Ranks'. Each rank has a 'name', 'position' and 'active' column. My user only sees ranks where 'active' is true. When a new rank is created a position is automatically generated for it. I designed it so that positions are assigned based on what order they are created: the 1st created rank has position = 1, the 2nd position = 2, etc... This part is working fine.

The issue I have is when a rank is deactivated and then a new one is created.

For example, I create 3 new ranks:
1. White
2. Blue
3. Green

Then I deactivate 'Blue' and create a new rank 'Purple':
1. White
3. Green
3. Purple

Whereas I want it to look like:
1. White
2. Green
3. Purple

If I were then to deactivate 'White' I would want it to be:
1. Green
2. Purple

Model

```
class Rank < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :activity, optional: true
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { minimum: 1, maximum: 50 }
  default_scope -> { order(position: :asc) }
  has_many :student_ranks
  has_many :students, through: :student_ranks
  before_create :assign_position
  before_create :change_position_if_duplicate
  after_update :change_position_if_duplicate

  def num_of_ranks_in_activity
      self.activity.ranks.where(active: true).count
  end

  private

  # Automatically assigns position to rank
  def assign_position
    self.position = num_of_ranks_in_activity + 1
  end
end
```

Schema

```
create_table "ranks", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.integer  "position"
  t.integer  "activity_id"
  t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  t.boolean  "active",      default: true
  t.index ["activity_id"], name: "index_ranks_on_activity_id", using: :btree
end
```

I have tried to reduce a position by 1 if it is a duplicate:

```
def change_position_if_duplicate
  p = self.position
  self.activity.ranks.where(active: true).each do |r|
    r.position -= 1 if r.position == p
  end
end
```

or to reassign each position based on created_at each time there's a change:

```
def change_position_if_duplicate
  sorted_by_date = self.activity.ranks.where(active: true).sort_by &:created_at
  n = 1
  sorted_by_date.each do |r|
    r.position = n
    n += 1
  end
end
```

But neither of those solutions made any change to the existing positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to happen if you have ranks 1, 2 and 3 and you deactivate rank 1? does 2 become 1 and 3 become 2? or next rank will be 4?

If you want the second option, instead of counting and adding one, get the highest posistion and add 1 to that:

```
def assign_position
  self.position = self.activity.ranks.where(active: true).last.position + 1
end
```

If you want to fix the position of the rest of the ranks, then check if the `active` attribute changed and update the active ranks with higher position:

```
after_update :check_deactivated

def check_deactivated
  if active_changed? and !active
    self.activity.ranks.where(active: true).where('position > ?', self.position).update_all('position = position-1')
  end
end
```

Comment: I have edited the question to show what I want to happen if I have ranks 1, 2 and 3 and I then deactivate rank 1.

Answer (score 0):

This should be solve your problem:

```
class Rank < ApplicationRecord
  ..
  after_update :reassign_positions, if: :active_changed?

  private

  def reassign_positions
    ranks = activity.ranks
    active_ranks = ranks.where(active: true).order(created_at: :asc)
    deactive_ranks = ranks.where(active: false)
    deactive_ranks.update_all(position: -1) if deactive_ranks.any?
    active_ranks.each_with_index { |rank, index| rank.update(position: index + 1) }
  end
  ..
end
```